# Arraylist access with an index generated in jsp script

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have an Arraylist of custom objects in servlet.

```
Arraylist<Book> allBooks = new Arraylist<>();
```

Inside my JSP I am populating a `<select>` dropdown by `allBooks`.

```
<select onchange="js_function()">
    <option></option>....
</select>
```

The `js_function()` is in an on page script where I get all information on the item selected by the user such as item serial no in the dropdown like below:

```
var valueIndex = document.getElementById("my_books").selectedIndex;
```

Now if I want to access the `allBooks` by that `valueIndex` inside that script, how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to do it this way, right? I have to look for some other way around.

Comment: have you thought about using ajax ? with ajax you will send an arraylist as a json response from your servlet and process it in the ajax result function

Comment: yea! I have implemented Ajax. It's working great now, Thanks!